# How can I access profile fields with a % variable in Drupal Actions?

Tags: actions

I have an action setup in drupal to e-mail me when a new user registers for the site. Right now it is only telling me their user name (%username). Is there a variable that can access added fields so I can get their real name (First Last), or another way to add this info to the action message? So instead of my new user action having a message like:

"%username created an account" -> "jschmoe created and account"

I could have:

"%first_name %last_name (%username) created an account" -> "Joe Schmoe (jschmoe) created an account".

I'm using Content Profile module for the first and last name fields, though have few enough users at the moment that I could switch to Profile module fields.

Comment: I already have Profile and Content Profile. I just need to know how to access the field values from actions. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the [Realname](http://drupal.org/project/realname) module together with [Token and Token Actions](http://drupal.org/project/token).